# R Append character to percentage of rows randomly

Tags: r, append

I have a dataframe 'df' that looks like this:

| Date | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-14 13:00:00 | AMRO | 3 |
| 2022-03-14 13:10:00 | AMRO | 4 |
| 2022-03-14 13:20:00 | BTYW | 5 |
| 2022-03-14 13:30:00 | MALL | 6 |
| 2022-03-14 13:40:00 | AMRO | 7 |
| 2022-03-14 13:50:00 | CHSP | 8 |
| 2022-03-14 14:00:00 | AMRO | 40 |
| 2022-03-14 14:10:00 | AMRO | 50 |
| 2022-03-14 14:20:00 | DEJU | 60 |
| 2022-03-14 14:30:00 | AMRO | 70 |
| 2022-03-14 14:40:00 | AMRO | 80 |
| 2022-03-14 14:50:00 | CHSP | 90 |

I want to add a space and the number 1 to the trailing side of the values in 'Value 1' for 40% of the rows, but do some randomly, so that the result looks like:

| Date | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-14 13:00:00 | AMRO 1 | 3 |
| 2022-03-14 13:10:00 | AMRO 1 | 4 |
| 2022-03-14 13:20:00 | BTYW | 5 |
| 2022-03-14 13:30:00 | MALL | 6 |
| 2022-03-14 13:40:00 | AMRO | 7 |
| 2022-03-14 13:50:00 | CHSP 1 | 8 |
| 2022-03-14 14:00:00 | AMRO | 40 |
| 2022-03-14 14:10:00 | AMRO | 50 |
| 2022-03-14 14:20:00 | DEJU 1 | 60 |
| 2022-03-14 14:30:00 | AMRO 1 | 70 |
| 2022-03-14 14:40:00 | AMRO | 80 |
| 2022-03-14 14:50:00 | CHSP | 90 |

Is there an easy way to go about doing this so that if I want to change the percentage of rows that get modified in future instances I can?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sample some proportion of observations numbers (.4 in this case) and then for those observation numbers append a 1 to `Value1`. You can change the proportion that get append with 1 by changing .4 to some other value in this part of the code: `round(nrow(tib)*.4)`.

```r
library(dplyr)
tib <- tibble::tribble(
~Date,  ~Value1,    ~Value2,
"2022-03-14 13:00:00",  "AMRO", 3,
"2022-03-14 13:10:00",  "AMRO", 4,
"2022-03-14 13:20:00",  "BTYW", 5,
"2022-03-14 13:30:00",  "MALL", 6,
"2022-03-14 13:40:00",  "AMRO", 7,
"2022-03-14 13:50:00",  "CHSP", 8,
"2022-03-14 14:00:00",  "AMRO", 40,
"2022-03-14 14:10:00",  "AMRO", 50,
"2022-03-14 14:20:00",  "DEJU", 60,
"2022-03-14 14:30:00",  "AMRO", 70,
"2022-03-14 14:40:00",  "AMRO", 80,
"2022-03-14 14:50:00",  "CHSP", 90)
```

```r
rows <- sample(1:nrow(tib), round(nrow(tib)*.4), replace=FALSE)
tib <- tib %>% 
  mutate(Value1 = ifelse(row_number() %in% rows, paste0(Value1, " 1"), Value1))

tib
#> # A tibble: 12 × 3
#>    Date                Value1 Value2
#>    <chr>               <chr>   <dbl>
#>  1 2022-03-14 13:00:00 AMRO        3
#>  2 2022-03-14 13:10:00 AMRO        4
#>  3 2022-03-14 13:20:00 BTYW        5
#>  4 2022-03-14 13:30:00 MALL        6
#>  5 2022-03-14 13:40:00 AMRO 1      7
#>  6 2022-03-14 13:50:00 CHSP 1      8
#>  7 2022-03-14 14:00:00 AMRO 1     40
#>  8 2022-03-14 14:10:00 AMRO       50
#>  9 2022-03-14 14:20:00 DEJU 1     60
#> 10 2022-03-14 14:30:00 AMRO       70
#> 11 2022-03-14 14:40:00 AMRO       80
#> 12 2022-03-14 14:50:00 CHSP       90
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>